# Spring MVC get Jackson JSON as parameter

Tags: json, spring-mvc, parameters

Hello In frist time I want apologize if my english isn't so good
I want send Multipart request to the server by Apache HttpClient. This request consist from several types of parts. One of these part is JSON. JSON is created by Jackson.

```
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080/synchronize");
        HttpResponse response =null;
        CProject project = new CProject();
        project.setId(10L);
        project.setName("name");
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(project);
        MultipartEntity multipart = new MultipartEntity( HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

        multipart.addPart("project", new StringBody(json,"application/json",Charset.forName("UTF-8")) );
        httppost.setEntity(multipart);
        response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

Structure of CProject is very simple

```
public class CProject implements Serializable{
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
}
```

And I wand catch this request on server as parameter with anotations @RequestParam or @ModelAttribute but no with @RequestBody because this catch full request - and I need send multiply parameters(Multipart Entity).

Code on server

```
@RequestMapping (value = "/synchronize", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody
    List<Object> getRequest (@RequestParam CProject project, HttpServletResponse response)
    {
            return null;

    }
```

Problem is that variable project is created but its atributes are null.
I try several tutorials on net what works with @RequestBody and send request on server and set full header  as "application/json". And my application works if I change header of full request as JSON and send them on server, and catch this as @RequestBody on server this work. But I need send json as parameter.

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: http://blog.springsource.com/2010/01/25/ajax-simplifications-in-spring-3-0/

Comment: yes I found this tutorial but he catch json as @RequestBody and second json is simple string and with this spring has no problem but I need send more complex json as parameter - class CProject is only for example. But thants for interest.